# Linker error, undefined reference

Tags: winapi

I am an absolute beginner. This is my first C++ code. Taking from the default project in Dev C++, youtube tutorials, and some intuition, I came up with the simple code below. I know the answer is going to be easy. I just can't seem to paste together answers from other posts the fix for mine. Any help you provide is GREATLY appreciated!!!

I get "undefined reference to CreateProcessWithLogonW" error.

```
#include <windows.h>


/* Declare Windows procedure */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND textfield;


/* Make the class name into a global variable */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpszArgument,
int nFunsterStil)

{
HWND hwnd; /* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages; /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl; /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure; /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS; /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL; /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0; /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0; /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush (COLOR_3DFACE);

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
0, /* Extended possibilites for variation */
szClassName, /* Classname */
"Files open on Mars",/* Title Text */
WS_SYSMENU, /* default window */
CW_USEDEFAULT, /* Windows decides the position */
CW_USEDEFAULT, /* where the window ends up on the screen */
444, /* The programs width */
175, /* and height in pixels */
HWND_DESKTOP, /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
NULL, /* No menu */
hThisInstance, /* Program Instance handler */
NULL /* No Window Creation data */
);

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
/* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
TranslateMessage(&messages);
/* Send message to WindowProcedure */
DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}


/* This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage() */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message) /* handle the messages */
{

case WM_CREATE:

CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Open files"),
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
10,10,80,25,
hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL
);

textfield = CreateWindow("STATIC",
"Please click the button to retrieve a list of open files on server",
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
10,50,400,25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

textfield = CreateWindow("STATIC",
"Message at bottom of box",
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
10,120,400,25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

break;

case WM_COMMAND:

if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {


CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"me", L"company", L"xxxxxx", 0, 0, L"c:\\files.cmd", 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
MessageBox(hwnd, "A text file with all of the open files has been placed on your desktop", "Open Files", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

}



break;

case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage (0); /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
break;
default: /* for messages that we don't deal with */
return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx), `CreateProcessWithLogonW` is defined in `Advapi32.lib`. You need to pass that library to the linker.